# Should unrelated non-dominant terms be dropped?

Tags: big-o

When we have `O(N + logN)` we drop `logN` as a non-dominant term.

When we have `O(N + M)` we have to keep both terms because these terms are unrelated.

What happens if we have something like `O(N + logM)`? On one hand, terms are still unrelated. On the other hand even if `M` is very big and `N` is very small `N` will sooner or later surpass `logM` so maybe `N` should be considered the dominant term. Should `logM` be dropped in this case or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because we use big-O notation, we're interested in the upper bound. For the 1st case `O(N + logN)` we can omit `logN` because it grows more slowly than `N`. See it on the [graph](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4IiwiY29sb3IiOiIjRTAyNjI2In0seyJ0eXBlIjowLCJlcSI6ImxvZyh4KSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzIwN0RENCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d).

The last two cases should keep both terms because we can't surely say in the common case what's grows slowly or faster.